# Genymotion Android Issue:screen is always flashing

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I have install the Genmotion emulator2.0.1+VirtualBox4.3.2,it runs without error,but the screen is always flashing.Someone can help me?

Comment: enable graphic support from virtualbox !

Comment: It didn't work.I reinstalled the genymotion and then works like charm,pretty strange.thanks all the same

Comment: @Jerome... Genymotion has its share of bugs ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled the genymotion and then works like charm,pretty strange.but it's the solution

Comment: Me too, reinstalling with sudo did the trick